# Reading sorted array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Why `$val` is Array(1), but not the numeric value? I expected that `$selected as $k => $val` should return each line from the array `$selected`. Thus, `$k` must be a numeric key (it is) and `$val` must be corresponding numeric value (but it's an array instead of simple integer).
So, how do I correctly save sorted keys and values in array `$ind` and `$ranks`?

```
<?php

        $selected = array();

        for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
            $selected[] = array($i => rand(0,5));
        }

        arsort($selected);

        $ind = array();
        $rank = array();
        foreach($selected as $k => $val) {
           $ind[] = $k;
           $rank[] = $val;
        }
?>
```

UPDATE:
For incstance, this code..

```
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    $selected[$i] = rand(0,5);
}
```

provided the array:
[0] => 5, [1] => 3, [2] => 2, [3] => 5, [4] => 3

Once I sorted it, initial keys are deleted, right? How can I find initial keys [0]-[4] of randomly generated values after sorting the array?

Comment: The keys are not deleted.  The are kept since you are using arsort which maintains original relationship of keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your likely solution is to change

```
$selected[] = array($i => rand(0,5));
```

to

```
$selected[] = rand(0,5);
```

Doing so will yield `$ind` and `$rank` like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 0
    [4] => 0
)
```

The best way to do what you want, is to just use the resultant array, for example:

`$selected`

```
Array
(
    [1] => 5
    [2] => 5
    [4] => 4
    [0] => 2
    [3] => 1
)
```

Comment: In  this case, once I sorted the array, how do I know its initial index (key = 0,1,2,3,4)?

Comment: See my edit.  The `arsort` will maintain the orinal keys, as you can see in the output of `print_r($selected)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need

```
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    $selected[$i] = rand(0,5);
}
```

Comment: Once I sorted the array (arsort), how do I know initial (unsorted) indexes of each value (keys = 0,1,2,3,4)?

Answer (score 0):

Your array structure will look like this:

```
array(
    0 => array(0 => 1),
    1 => array(1 => 4),
    ...
)
```

because you're assigning an *array* here:

```
$selected[] = array($i => rand(0,5));
```

You just want this instead:

```
$selected[] = rand(0,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am not pretty much sure what you are trying to do but following code is creating an array of arrays.

```
$selected = array();

        for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
            $selected[] = array($i => rand(0,5));
        }
```

So $val will be an array. You can try following code:

```
$selected = array();

    for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
        $selected[] = rand(0,5);
    }
```

Thanks